# Broken UI: Hover Popup from Hovering Over Tags Hides Tags Textbox

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, popups

When I am entering the tags for a question I am working on it will often cover up what I am typing with the "tag explanation" box.  This drives me nuts, is there any way to have it stop popping up over what I am writing?

Example:

I've tried to show where my cursor is with the red line.
[image]

Once I start typing it adds the tag box below the **Tags** header and above the tags text box.  This pushes down my text box and puts my cursor on the tag information box which causes a popup that hides my textbox:

[image]

You can see from the tag information box that I have typed `visual-stu` but it's covered in the text box by the tag information box. Would it be possible to put the tags or information boxes in a different place?  At the very least could popups not show unless it finds a definition for the tag?

Let me know if any of this is confusing...

Comment: No, that makes sense. I never noticed this because Chrome (what I usually use) doesn't fire a hover event until you actually move the mouse; but Firefox is indeed not that picky. Will take a look.

Comment: And while balpha is fixing this: just move your mouse away after clicking in the tag input. (I assume your mouse pointer is still at the place where the cursor shows in your first image.)

Comment: @Arjan: Yeah, another reason I never noticed. I always move the mouse cursor away after clicking into a text box. Some habits make you blind :)

Comment: @abe, Maybe you should blur your email address ...

Comment: @Charlie Oh it's far too late for that.  He's signed on to about 50 unicorn and pony related email lists now.

Comment: @Adam, that's fine.  I'm into it.

Comment: @Abe: Then start here: http://games.adultswim.com/robot-unicorn-attack-twitchy-online-game.html

Comment: Please fix this!

Answer (score 2):

After the next build, the tag preview will be *below* the input box. That way, the box will not shift down, hence your cursor stays in the same place.

The reason to put it *above* the box was so the auto-complete results don't block the preview, but in hindsight, that shouldn't really cause any problem. And having the preview below also adds some consistency with the WMD editor, which has its preview below as well.